# SQL Query to know how many documents have expired month by month

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, count, where-clause

What I want to achieve, is to get how many documents are expiring on each month, so then i can create a chart with theese values (still don't know how).

- Table : document

```
idDoc, client, fileName, format, expirationDate
'1', '22', 'SAMPLE_XXX', 'JPG', '2020-05-31'
```

- Table : months

```
idType, description
'107001', 'January'
```

- What i've acomplished by now (almost nothing)

```
SELECT 
    verticalAxis as Y,
    horizontalAxis as X,
    `values` as vals
FROM
(
   SELECT m.description as horizontalAxis, SUM(d.idDoc) as `values`
   FROM months m,
   document d
   WHERE d.client = 22
) graph
GROUP BY X,Y;
```

So what I'm trying to get is all documents which are expiring, grouped by months.
Is there any way to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand how the `month` table fits in the picture, given its structure. You can, however, get the result that you want directly from `document` using aggregation:

```
select date_format(expirationDate, '%Y-%m-01') expiration_month, count(*) no_docs
from document
where client = 22
group by expiration_month
```

This generates a resultset made of two columns: the beginning of the expiration month, and then count of rows whose `expirationMonth` belongs to that month.

Comment: And is there anyway to get only data from the current year? I saw I have registres from 2009 and it isn't necessary

Comment: @Martinez: `where client = 22 and expirationDate > date_format(current_date, '%Y-01-01')`

Comment: So basically if I want the current year I have to ````and ad.expirationDate >= date_format(current_date, '%Y-01-01')
and ad.expirationDate <= date_format(current_date, '%Y-12-31')````

Comment: Can you upvote my question so I can ask another question related to this please?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL lets you extract the year-month from the date.  So one method is:

```
select extract(year_month from expiration_date) as yyyymm, count(*)
from document
group by yyyymm;
```